# Mesh artifacts after Knife project

Tags: artifacts, knife-tool, project

I used a Knife projection tool to cut the cockpit window out of a fuselage. But after that, I get some artifacts. (These weird lines coming out of the window.) Cannot understand what is the cause for them. Thanks in advance.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to upload the file? I guess it is just a topology problem caused by the knife project.

Comment: Uploaded .blend

Answer (score 1):

Ok I took a look at your blend file and your mesh has a **lot** of **n-gons** and **triangles** :

[image]

They are the culprit behind that ugly shading that you see and to avoid those, you should always model with only quads as much as you can.

I see that your original model was made of only quads but the knife project is what caused the mess.

To solve this, you would need **a lot of retopology**.

There are other ways to solve this problem but this is what I would do :

Place the cursor at the origin of you object (the fuselage), you can do that with `SHIFT` + `S` and then `Cursor to Selected`, and create a new cube from there.

Delete all the vertices of the new cube except for 1 and add a mirror modifier to the cube with `Clipping` enabled :

[image]

Turn on snapping with `Snap to` set to `face` :
[image]

Then you can begin to **remodel** your fuselage by beginning with the windows :

[image]

This may take a little time but the presence of your ancient mesh with the use of snapping make it really fast and easy.

[image]

If you keep you topology to quad only, you should avoid the problems mentioned in the question :
[image]

Just remember a few tips to ease your modeling for shapes like this :

- Try to always surround holes and extrusions with loop cuts.
- Always plan your topology carefully before modeling
- Avoid odd number of vertices around holes

There are many tutorial online if you want to learn modeling.